# CSS animation IE mobile

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have a CSS step animation and it works fine on all browsers except IE Mobile, I have searched on the internet and I haven't found anything about this, I took some other animations from the internet and it is the same result.
Here is a demo( http://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/yldGp ) ,this bug is visible on the bottom shadow.
Is this a browser issue or is the animation?

```
.monster {width: 190px; height: 240px;margin: 2% auto;background: url('http://treehouse-code-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/CSS-DD/codepen/blog/monster.png') left center;animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;}@keyframes play {100% { background-position: -1900px; }}
```

Comment: "I took some other animations from the internet and it is the same result" suggests its a browser inconsistency.

Comment: I think that too, but I want a proof to show to the client.

Comment: it is an IE render issue